# passing values from specific csv columns into string variables in python3

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to iterate over a csv file that has the following structure:

[image: csv exmp]

save the last and first names in string variables for each line in the csv and then use it for another search. (I know it works if I just pass strings)

how do I save the values from each row for the names in the variables?
this is what I have so far:

```
import elasticsearch
from csv import reader, DictReader
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan
import json

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch("http://XXX.168.56.XXX:9200/")

# iterate over each line as a ordered dictionary 
with open("New Orders.csv", "r") as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        #print(row)
        fn =  row['First Name']
        ls = row['Last Name']
        es_response = scan(
            es,
            index="orders2",
            query={
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"match": {"First Name": fn}},
                            {"match": {"Last Name": ls}},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
        )
        for item in es_response:
            print(json.dumps(item))
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer :)

```
import pandas as pd
import elasticsearch
from csv import reader, DictReader
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan
import json

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch("http://XXX.168.56.XXX:9200/")
df = pd.read_csv("New Orders.csv")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # print(row)
    fn = row[0]
    ls = row[1]
    es_response = scan(
        es,
        index="orders2",
        query={
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"match": {"First Name": fn}},
                        {"match": {"Last Name": ls}},
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    )
    for item in es_response:
        print(json.dumps(item))
```